# using another class in a camelprocessor

Tags: java, xml

i have a csv file which i change into a xml file which works fine. but now i need two xml values out of this file and write it into a third node.
i tried it with the following code

```
@DataField(pos = 10) //which is 3
@XmlElement(required = true)
private int Number1;
@DataField(pos = 11) //which is 0.75
@XmlElement(required = true)
private double Number2;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected double Overall=Number1*Number2;
```

so the xml _should outcome as follows:

```
<Number1>3</Number1>
<Number2>0.75</Number2>
<Overall>2.25</Overall>
```

but turns out like this:

```
<Number1>3</Number1>
<Number2>0.75</Number2>
<Overall>0.0</Overall>
```

when i write protected double Overall=Number1*0.75+2; it returns 2 for overall, so it appears that it sets Number1=0 and not 3 how it should.. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the 'overall' variable in the declaration part of it. When the JAXB sets the values in the elements using the setters, the other variables might not have been initialized.

Calculate the 'overall' whenever the number1 and number2 changes.

```
private void calculateOverall(){//new method to write
   this.overall = this.number1*this.number2+2;
}

public void setNumber1(int number){//modified setter method
   this.number1 = number;
   calculateOverall();//calculate the variable afresh when setting values
}

public void setNumber2(double number){//modified setter method
   this.number2 = number;
   calculateOverall();//calculate the variable afresh when setting values
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast help, but still it just sets out the +2 (so its <overall>2.0</overall) even with the getOverall in the declaration :/

Comment: @KleineKiwi I think the updated answer should work. I was hurrying with the answer for that moment. Check now.

Comment: @KleineKiwi did this help you?

Comment: kinda, i just dont know how to integrate the calculateOverall back into the overall, tried with getoverall  and return, but didnt work :/(sorry i am still kinda noobish

Comment: @KleineKiwi :D I have given the code to you. You just have to put those methods. Nothing else. what are you stuck at?

Comment: well i insert what u gave me, but instead of 2 or even 4.25 it still is 0 :/

Comment: @KleineKiwi I think that should work. Did you put debugger on setNumber1() and setNumber2() ? Did you debug it?

Comment: mypack.Artikel$JaxbAccessorF_Overall@28fd2ceb

Comment: @KleineKiwi Debug it and see how values are coming into it? I can just help you, i cant test your program from here.. :/

Comment: i did debug it but somehow it doesnt use the setnumbers at all so it returns without value, and i dont know how to inesrt them.. or do anything.. sorry, kinda frustrated

Comment: Should be problem with method signature. Use eclipse or the IDE you use to generate the setter and getter methods and change the logic inside it. leaving for the day. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the calculation at the declaration level, i.e. when you are declaring the field `Overall` you are deriving it's value from some other variables which are yet to be initialized.
To avoid this, you can do the calculation in some method.

Answer (score 0):

added following in the class above the artikelclass:

```
void calc() {

    Artikel.calculateOverall();
}
```

fixed it :3